# Using OpenID Connect with IdentityServer 2

Tags: thinktecture-ident-server, openid-connect

I want to use `OpenID Connect` for authenticating users for one of my projects. Through my research i have found that `IdentityServer 3` supports OpenID Connect. But what i want to know is can i use `OpenID Connect` with `IdentityServer 2` for my application? I was not able to find anything on the web so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes Identity Server v2 supports OpenID Connect, see: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer2/tree/master/samples/OIDC